# What is advantage of having interface in Spring Boot REST API / Micro services?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, multiple-inheritance

I have DAO interface and DAOImpl class on my Spring boot REST API project. But some of my teammates were telling me that it is not necessary to have an interface in REST API.

Their argument is if the code is shared as a .jar file (eg. Database Driver jar file) then it is necessary to have an interface. Since jar is added in the classpath and the end user can override the methods defined in the jar file. Whereas REST API's are deployed in servers and can be consumed by any programming language via HTTP

I know there is no concrete answer for this. But I just want to know the advantages/disadvantages of having an interface in REST API / Microservice

Comment: This is nonsense. What does having an interface for your DAO have to do with having a REST API? These are 2 completely separated/independent things.

Comment: You have to distingush between REST and any framework/programming language. While for the latter OO/SOLID and here the [interface segregation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle) and [open-closed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open%E2%80%93closed_principle) principles apply, the former one already is build on top of a [uniform interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#Uniform_interface) provided by its underlying transport protocol (HTTP) and the operations/actions it offers.

Answer (score 0):

The advantage of using an interface is when you use a service that is common by all your Rest API like the security service with spring-security.

Answer (score 0):

"interface" is NOT specific to REST API (or) Spring, it is one of the Object oriented principle, in Java programming terms, it is "interface".

Your friends are partially true.

In general "interface" are used to define the "protocol" and let the implementation be specific to "implementer".

Now the counter argument I can make is, what if your company wants to standardize the process between "departments" (or) "projects", specific to this DAO business specification (forgot about sharing as .jar or something else)?

Answer (score 0):

Interface is the best practice in this situation and it takes 1 minute to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Once I did a hiring test to a company in UK and i got this feedback:

> "And the dreaded Impl classes…"

At this point I started questioning the use of interfaces in microservices where everything is accessed through HTTP. After putting some thoughts into this I realized I never had a situation where Interfaces were really helpful in this situation.

I built a few personal projects without them (unless it's required by Spring) and I liked it. Being able to change services without painting them red by the IDE was a big plus.

Also, it's less code to maintain. I would vote up for it for new projects.